# why u-boot "gzwrite" command is not working properly?

Tags: embedded, gzip, u-boot

I have a compressed `image.wic` loaded into my board RAM address 0x600000000. I am using u-boot command `gzwrite` to uncompress it to the eMMC:

```
=> gzwrite mmc 1 600000000 0x4E6C254 100000 0
1079002112/1079002112
    uncompressed 1079002112 of 1079002112
    crcs == 0xa9cd7080/0x940992c8
```

As shown in the output above, the expected crc is different from the calculated crc. Therefore, the uncompressed image is corrupt.

Moreover, `gzwrite` is taking 20 minutes to write my 1GB image, whereas it is stated [here](https://boundarydevices.com/u-boot-gunzip-and-write-on-i-mx6/) that "Extracting a 4GiB image to eMMC generally should take under 6 minutes".